# How to show popup/dialog after another popup/dialog shows up

Tags: android

I'va a plan for showing success dialog message after loading bar shows up,That's loading Dialog i set 4s to dissmiss,can i show success dialog after 4s loading dialog?

Here my code :

1.Checkout.java

```
package com.example.uts;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class checkout extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView total,kembalian;
    EditText tunai;
    Button proses,acc;
    Dialog dialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.checkout);
    total = findViewById(R.id.total_checkout);
    kembalian = findViewById(R.id.kembalian);
    tunai = findViewById(R.id.tunai);
    proses=findViewById(R.id.btnProses);
    acc=findViewById(R.id.btnAcc);

    final LoadingDialog loadingDialog=new LoadingDialog(checkout.this);
    total.setText("Rp."+getIntent().getStringExtra("totalid"));

//its working for loading dialog,i need to show success dialog,4000 = 4s
    proses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loadingDialog.startLoadingDialog();
            Handler handler=new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                }
            },4000);
        }
    });
}
```

}

2. LoadingDialog.java (success dialog also)

   package com.example.uts;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;

   class LoadingDialog {
   private Activity activity;
   private AlertDialog dialog,accDialog;

   ```
    LoadingDialog(Activity myActivity){
        activity=myActivity;
    }

    void startLoadingDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading,null));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        dialog = builder.create();;
        dialog.show();
    }
    void dismiss(){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    void startAcc(){
        AlertDialog.Builder acc=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        LayoutInflater AccLay=activity.getLayoutInflater();
        acc.setView(AccLay.inflate(R.layout.acc,null));
        acc.setCancelable(false);
        accDialog = acc.create();
        accDialog.show();
    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below way

```
Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    checkout.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable{
                         //show the success dialog                                         })

                }
            },4000);
```